# Animate a ViewGroup height using GestureDetectorCompat

Tags: android, android-animation

I am using `GestureDetectorCompat` to do a very basic animation of the `ViewGroup` height. On the `onScroll` event I am taking the `ViewGroup` and subtracting or adding the `distanceY` I am getting from the `onScroll` method signature.

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) container.getLayoutParams();

    params.height = (int) (container.getHeight() + distanceY);
    container.setLayoutParams(params);

    return true;
}
```

The animation is very choppy/flickery. Am I missing something here? Is there a better way to animate a `View` height according to motion events?

Another wondering I have, When I drag down the view, `distanceY` from the `onScroll` event contains positive and negative values. Shouldn't dragging down consist of only negative values? how can I tell if user is dragging down or up?

Comment: why use onScroll instead of `onTouch` ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya I am using onScroll of GestureDetectorCompat which reads event from onTouch. It just gives access to convenient stuff like onFling and so on.

Comment: As of my opinion, You need to this height related work in `onTouch` event.